# Python + Tornado Restart after editing files

Tags: python, reload, tornado, restart

I just start learning Python + Tornado for my web servers. Every time I modify some code on my python scripts or templates I have to stop the in my terminal (CTRL+C) and restart it (python server.py) and I want a more effective way to do this, that after modifying code in some files the server automatically restarts.

Previously I working with NodeJS and using supervisor to do this.

Also there is a way to reload my tab in Google Chrome so I can see the changes without reloading (F5)

Currently I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 and Sublime Text 2 and using CTRL+B on sublime text, but if the server is already running generates an error because the address and port is in use. There is a fix for that without changing the port.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are looking for automatic reloading of .py files during development. In your `tornado.web.Application()` put `debug=True` after your handlers.

I don't think you should do this in production environment, because such implementation typically use a background thread to actively scan files for changes, which may slow down your application.

Comment: Actually I believe tornado does not use a separate thread for this but instead registers handlers on its IOLoop. Nevertheless it incurs an overhead. Also, debug messages should not be used in production anyway.

Comment: It's possible just to pass in "autoreload=True" now. And there is a documentation page here: http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/autoreload.html

Answer (score 5):

You need to turn `autoreload` on:

```
tornado.autoreload.start()
tornado.autoreload.watch('myfile')
```

Complete example at https://gist.github.com/renaud/10356841